# Logic Apps - I can create a row in dataverse with null in lookup field, but i can't update a row with null

Tags: azure-logic-apps, dataverse

When I use the dataverse connector 'create a row (preview)', I can create a row in the table 'Account' with the field 'primarycontactid' null. When I try do this with 'update a row (preview)' however, I get an error:

{
"error": {
"code": "0x80060888",
"message": "The supplied reference link --  -- is invalid. Expecting a reference link of the form /entityset(key)."
}
}

this is the body:
"body": {
"name": "Test2",
"primarycontactid@odata.bind": ""
}

When I adjust the code itself to "primarycontactid@odata.bind": null, it works.

but i need to have something like this (so this works on create, not update):
"primarycontactid@odata.bind": "@{if(empty(body('Get_Contact')?['value']),null,concat('contacts(',body('Get_Contact')?['value']?[0]?['contactid'] ,')'))}"

I tried filling it with null, with empty quotes, with contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I have received the same error but after following the below process, I could able to update the field with null value. Below is the flow of my Logic app.

[image]

***In my codeview***

```
"body": {
"crc76_primarycontactid": "@{null}"
}
```

### Results

***Before updating***

[image]

***After updating***

[image]

Comment: This is my codeview:
                    "body": {
                        "primarycontactid@odata.bind": "@{null}"
                    },

So it is the same, right?
On a test run, when i look to the raw inputs, it translates to this:
    "body": {
        "primarycontactid@odata.bind": ""
    }

And still the same error. If it works on your side, maybe it's some kind of configuration.

Comment: Also, i have to us odata.bind. Without it i get "Error identified in Payload provided by the user "

Comment: Ah i see, you are making a string field null. That i can do. Now try to make the lookup field null.